# Styling of system cursor and text selection options dialog

Tags: android

I have integrated [this color picker](https://code.google.com/archive/p/devmil-android-color-picker/) as a module in my app, with some modifications.

I'm finding some odd styling which I do not know where it is coming from.  Firstly, there is a solid blue background behind the cursor when you click into an `EditText`:

[image]

And when you long press on the text in the `EditText` to bring up the usual copy/paste options dialog, I find that there is a large solid blue background behind the dialog:

[image]

Where might these be coming from, and how can I remove them?

The style applicable to the Dialog is presently as follows:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyleLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You should share your code for those calls, rather than images. Which theme are you overriding?

Comment: @Pztar I've added the xml styling being used

Comment: Show me the code for color picker dialog as you had added in your code. i want to see how you have added this dialog theme(MyAlertDialogStyleLight) in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a fix in the end.  The answer is to swap the values in the following properties, from:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

to:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you provided, I think you should try to change `android:background` to `transparent`:

```
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

But it's may affect other dialogs use the style `MyAlertDialogStyleLight`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: that solves one problem but creates another: the background behind the cursor feature is indeed then transparent, but so is the entire dialog background, so that you can see the underlying content below the dialog.  Any way to change just the transparency of the cursor element? @Minhtdh

Comment: @drmrbrewer, I don't know either, it's depend on you use the style in code, I never use your library before, all I have is just a guess from the style you provided.